# Custom function to query database across Django views

Tags: python, django

In 'myapp' I have a model 'Profile', which shares a OnetoOneField relationship with my custom User model. In many of my views, I need to check if the user has a profile set up. So I have created a module 'profilecheck' which contains this function:

```
def has_profile(req):
    try:       
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=req.user)
        return profile
    except: 
        return False
```

In my views.py, I have the following:

```
from myapp.utils.profilecheck import has_profile
from myapp.models import Profile

def viewprofile(request):   
    if has_profile(request):
        context = {
            'profile': has_profile(request) 
        }
        return render(request, 'profile.html', context)         
    else:
        return render(request, 'setup_profile.html', {})
```

When called in the view, has_profile() always returns False. Any ideas why?

Comment: Edited in response to Aamir Adnan

Comment: if you try to `print(Profile.objects.all())` what happend? maybe your profile data isn't created yet, or maybe you are not logged in..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to use an undefined variable in the `has_profile` function. You are trying to use `request.user` but `request` is not defined hence it raises an exception which gets caught in `except` clause and that returns `False`, you need to pass request as a parameter to `has_profile` function.

Comment: Show me how you have updated the `has_profile` function and how you are calling it now.

Comment: In the context dictionary you are still not passing request as a parameter to `has_profile`. P.S store the `has_profile` results in a variable and do truth testing on variable instead of calling `has_profile` multiple times as that will hit database as many times you are going to call that function.

Comment: Edited again, it still returns false. Tried truth testing, still returns false. Besides I thought  that 'request' would have scope anywhere within viewprofile, so doesnt need to be passed as a parameter? And if I have to pass request as a parameter, do I also not have to pass user?

Comment: Come on.. try to debug the issue, if it is now retuning False then it means either the user profile does not exist or there is some other kind of exception, change `except` to `except Profile.DoesNotExist` avoid too broad exception clause.

Comment: In the `profilecheck` have you imported `Profile` model? This is down side of too borad except clause as you don't know what's happening.

Comment: Got it! Yes, it was because I did not import Profile. I'm a python beginner, assumed it only needed to be imported in views.py. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is exhibit 1235667 for why you should never use a blank `except`. If you had just caught the DoesNotExist exception only, the traceback would have told you immediately what was wrong.